# comboBox replace null to empty string

Tags: c#, methods, combobox

What can I do to detect when in comboBox I have null because user choose nothing, and replace it for empty string? I use for fill comboBox DataSource.

```
if (comboBoxTransport.SelectedItem.ToString() == null)
            comboBoxMaintenance.SelectedItem = "";
        this.dataGridViewOffer.DataSource = soc.FindOffer(comboBoxCountry.SelectedItem.ToString(), comboBoxAccommodation.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
            comboBoxTransport.SelectedItem.ToString(), comboBoxMaintenance.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();
```

I need it to correctly call method:

```
 public List<Oferty1> FindOffer(string country, string accommodation, string transport, string maintenance) {...}
```

Or in how other way can I convert null to string in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Ternary Operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to check it wherever you need:

```
comboBoxTransport.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBoxTransport.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

**Complete Code:**

```
if (comboBoxTransport.SelectedItem == null) //ToString can not be called if property is null
comboBoxMaintenance.SelectedItem = "";

this.dataGridViewOffer.DataSource = 
    soc.FindOffer(
                    comboBoxCountry.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBoxCountry.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                    comboBoxAccommodation.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBoxAccommodation.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                    comboBoxTransport.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBoxTransport.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                    comboBoxMaintenance.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBoxMaintenance.SelectedItem.ToString()
                ).ToList();
```